# Building matrix expressions for product of sum, isolating vector of constants

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, summation, products

This identity to build the matrix expression for the expression below is pretty straightforward:

$$
\left.\sum\limits_{j=1}^M \left( a_j \cdot f_{i,j} \right) \;\right|_{i=1}^N = \left[\begin{array}{}f_{1,1} & \ldots & f_{1,M} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ f_{N,1} & \ldots & f_{N,M} \end{array}\right] \cdot \left[\begin{array}{} a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_M \end{array}\right]
$$

Note that I'm oversimplifying my problem here. I need to understand if there is a way and, if yes, how could I build the proper matrix expression when I'm dealing with this kind of expression:

$$
\left.\prod\limits_{k=1}^P \sum\limits_{j=1}^M a_j \cdot \mathcal{T}_k \left[f_{i,j} \right]\;\right|_{i=1}^N
$$

where $M$, $N$ and $P$ are arbitrary non-negative integer numbers (with $N=M$) and $\mathcal{T}_k$ is the $k$-th operation over $f_{i,j}$.

What I need to do is to isolate $\sum\limits_{j=1}^M a_j$ in order to create the vector $\vec{a} =\left[\,\begin{array}{} a_1 & \cdots & a_M \end{array}\,\right]^T$ or, at least, a matrix $M\times P$ (if it is strictly necessary).

Could anybody help me out of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some attempts, I've figure it out:

$$
\left.\prod\limits_{k=1}^P \sum\limits_{j=1}^M a_j \cdot \mathcal{T}_k \left[f_{i,j} \right]\;\right|_{i=1}^N = 
\left[\begin{array}{} \prod\limits_{k=1}^P \mathcal{T}_k \left[f_{1,1} \right] & \ldots & \prod\limits_{k=1}^P \mathcal{T}_k \left[f_{1,M}\right] \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ \prod\limits_{k=1}^P \mathcal{T}_k \left[f_{N,1}\right] & \ldots & \prod\limits_{k=1}^P \mathcal{T}_k \left[f_{N,M}\right] \end{array}\right] \cdot \left[\begin{array}{} a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_M \end{array}\right]
$$

Thank you for those who have given a thought to this :-D